# Возвращение значение по указному ключу

Tags: java

В Map, в качестве ключа, я хочу искользовать собственный объект, ну положим Item, с переопределёнными методами hashCode и equals. Но когда я хочу получить значение, ранее положенное в Map я получаю null, в качестве примера привожу код.
Вопрос собственно в том, как можно реализовать код класса Item, чтобы в итоге Map мне вернул значение по указанному ключу?

```
public class Item {
    private Integer item;

    public Item(Integer item) { this.item = item; }

    public void setItem(Integer item) { this.item = item; }
    public Integer getItem() { return this.item; }

    public int hashCode() { return item * 31; }
    public boolean equals(Item item) { return this.hashCode() == item.hashCode(); }
    public String toString() { return item.toString(); }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String ... argv) {
        Map<Item, String> map = new HashMap<Item, String>();
        map.put(new Item(2), "test");

        System.out.println(map.get(new Item(2))); // Возвращает null
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/916953 - у меня двоится в глазах?

Comment: @Igor тоже задался таким вопросом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что вы не переопределили метод equals. В классе Object метод имеет сигнатуру

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
```

А вы создали свой метод equals со своей сигнатурой. Если вы пометите свой метод equals аннотацией @Override компилятор выдаст ошибку по этому поводу.
Следовательно измените метод equals в классе Item на

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj)
```

и у вас всё заработает )

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public int hashCode() { return item * 31; }
```

и так далее

Comment: Хитрый Игорь хайпит на неопытности юзеров

Comment: @SeeSharp  Мне чужого не надо: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/916953/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E-null#comment1511171_916953